# R function '...' argument scope

Tags: r, function, scope, parameter-passing

Tried this code via source()

```
f1 <- function(x, ...){
  print(y)
}

f1(x = 1, y = 2)
```

or this code via source()

```
f1 <- function(x, ...){
  y <- 2
  f2(x, y = y, ...)
}

f2 <- function(x, ...){
  print(y)
}

f1(x = 1)
```

Got this Error

```
Error in print(y) : object 'y' not found
```

I guess the '...' argument takes from the global environment?

Comment: I think it is not popping the values off the stack since you are not using the `x` value. The cold below (sorta) works.

Comment: Why are you trying to use `...` here? It doesn't make sense since you seem to want to have very specifically named variables. What exactly is the behavior you want?

Answer (score 0):

you should call y in your function as correct like this

```
f1 <- function(x, ...){
l <- list(...)
if(!is.null(l$y)) print(l$y)
}
f1(x = 1, y=2)
```

Comment: it works! so the '...' is actually an 'environment' thing, which needs list() to access?

Comment: it is about optional arguments. if you think you some times need  some optional arguments you use it as follow